# How to prepare text in all TXT files in folder for python via terminal?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, macos, unix, terminal

I have folder with a lot of TXT files (books) which have many special symbols (multiple spaces, paragraphs, #, -, '.', etc) in the beginning. It causes great variety of problems while reading the files in python (pandas). Usually it transfers into errors like:

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 29, saw 2
```

or

```
Found 0 texts.
```

Can I use some terminal script for text preconditioning? Your assistance will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

example for one file:

[image]

and code:

```
texts = []  # list of text samples
labels_index = {}  # dictionary mapping label name to numeric id
labels = []  # list of label ids
for name in sorted(os.listdir(TEXT_DATA_DIR)):
    path = os.path.join(TEXT_DATA_DIR, name)
    if os.path.isdir(path):
        label_id = len(labels_index)
        labels_index[name] = label_id
        for fname in sorted(os.listdir(path)):
            if fname.isdigit():
                fpath = os.path.join(path, fname)
                args = {} if sys.version_info < (3,) else {'encoding': 'utf-8'}
                with open(fpath, **args) as f:
                    t = f.read()
                    i = t.find('\n\n')  # skip header
                    if 0 < i:
                        t = t[i:]
                    texts.append(t)
                labels.append(label_id)


print('Found %s texts.' % len(texts))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the unicodedata.

```
text = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', text)
```

It Replaces unicode characters with their normal representations